# Why does garbage collection not work with threads?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, garbage-collection, nsoperation

Every thing works fine in my app up until I detach a thread to read audio data out of a file and process it.

Garbage Collection seems to not know anything about what happens on this thread no matter what I do. I've tried [NSThread self], [NSThread currentThread], [[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector]collectIfNeeded] and collectExhaustivly].
I switched to NSOperation with NSOperationQueue from NSThread.

None of these suggested solutions have worked. Most recently, I switched from NSMutableArrays to

`Float32* pfArray= calloc(numFloats, sizeof(Float32));`

to hold my data, and used 
`free(pfArray);`
to free that memory. This is working better, but still leaking a decent amount.

Garbage Collection does seem to start working to some extent after the "real mem" indicated in Activity Monitor hits some arbitrary number, but when it does appear to be working, it does NOT free all the memory being used. It just doesn't let it go much higher than the arbitrary threshold.

I've read that GC is the way to go, but now I'm unsure and have an almost fully written program.  Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Garbage collection indeed works on all threads of the app. You might have unwittingly kept a reference to some object rooted, thus leaking a subgraph; without the original code, however, not much can be said.

Comment: Dead on;  the collector works great with threaded applications.  It is significantly more efficient than non-GC code in a threaded app, much of the time.   Without more evidence, hard to say what you've done wrong.

Comment: I must add, rereading the question, that it is possible that he's mixing unmanaged memory calls (malloc-based) with managed ones. But again, without the original source it's hard to counsel.

Answer (score 1):

“`collectIfNeeded`” implies that it will not collect if collection isn't needed.

Use Instruments's Heapshot feature (part of the Allocations instrument) to find out what objects are remaining alive, and its Object Graph instrument to find out what is still holding on to the objects that you think should no longer be needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I hadn't used Instruments before. I've plugged the leak, but I still don't fully understand why the plug works. The _only_ way I got my program to stop leaking was to take all allocs, mallocs, and callocs out of my `[NSOperation main]` code. So it seems to me that GC can not keep track of allocations inside of NSOperation.

Comment: @subby: GC only tracks Cocoa objects; anything you allocate with `malloc`, `realloc`, or `calloc`, you still have to free. Where did you store the objects you created with `alloc`?

Comment: There are low-level functions that can allocate GC'd memory, so long that one remembers to mark all the `void*`s used with `__strong` to let the compiler know. See `NSAllocateCollectable` in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html